# Altair map with bivariate colormap

Tags: python, altair

I would like to create an Altair map having n distinct categories (each with a specific color) while
having a second variable that controls the alpha/shading/color of these categories?

Now, I am able to produce a map colored by category and using whatever custom color of my choice and I am able to produce a map with a continuous variable and using whatever colormap of my choice.
I am not sure, however, how to proceed to obtain what I am looking for.

I thought I could possibly add some extra color with something like this:
`.encode(alt.Color('properties.Cat2:O', scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_),alt.Color('properties.colmap2:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=cm_range_))`
but I feel like I am trying random stuff and not getting any closer.

**EDIT**

Following @jakevdp's comments I am trying to include an opacity argument. However, I am unsure about the proper syntax.

```
chart_json = json.loads(gdf.to_json())
chart_data= alt.Data(values=chart_json ['features'])
data_1km_geojson = alt.InlineData(values=val_1km, format=alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json'))
domain=['Label1','Label2']
range_=['#b0d247','#007bd1']
chart_layer1 = alt.Chart(chart_data).mark_geoshape().encode(
    alt.Color('properties.Cat2:O', scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_),title = "sometitle"),
    opacity=alt.Opacity('properties:OpacityVar:Q', bin=True),
).properties(
width=1100,
height=800
)
#Visualize the result
(background+chart_layer1).configure_view(stroke='white')
```

Additionally, the variable I am trying to use for the opacity argument has actually a very broad support (from 10.000 to 100Billions). Should I do a minmax normalization first?

Comment: You can't have two color encodings at once - the second one you specify will always override the first. Have you tried an opacity encoding?

Comment: Good suggestion with the opacity but I forgot to mention that the two categories never overlap. So opacity shouldn't be an issue. I'll see if I manage by adding a further layer (so each layer has its own colormap). I'll come back with an update, thanks for the comment by the way =)

Comment: I suggested the opacity channel not to deal with overlap, but because you asked about encoding a second variable by alpha or shading. The opacity encoding does precisely that.

Comment: @jakevdp I see, could you have a look at the approach I added (trying to follow your suggestion)? I have had a look at the [documentation for the opacity argument](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Opacity.html?highlight=opacity) but I am not sure I follow it completely and I am having some problem with my syntax

Comment: That syntax looks correct, assuming your data has a field named ``"properties:OpacityVar"``.

Comment: I am trying to plot a heatmap with 3 variables in 3 different colormaps on the same axis and I can't find a solution for Altair. The variables never overlap (lots of NaNs), like @CAPSLOCK example. 

I seen people masking arrays in order to do that with matplotlib (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036609/how-to-create-a-heat-map-with-multiple-colormaps) but nothing on Altair so far. Has anyone had any new ideas on this or has Altair any upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the comments by splitting up the variables on two different encodings (opacity and color) instead of having them both on color.