# How to combine two heatmaps in Seaborn in Python so both are shown in the same heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, heatmap

This is link to the data I'm  using:
https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/drug-use-by-age

I'm using Jupyter Lab, and here's the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/drug-use-by-age/drug-use-by-age.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col = 0)

df.dtypes
df.replace('-', np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[:,:].astype(float)
df = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'n']
#df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('-use')
df

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20, 8))

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1)
fig.colorbar(ax.collections[0], ax=ax,location="right", use_gridspec=False, pad=0.2)
#plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))
df_percentage = df.iloc[:,range(0,26,2)]
plot_precentage = sb.heatmap(df_percentage, cmap='Reds', ax=axes[0], cbar_kws={'format': '%.0f%%', 'label': '% used in past 12 months'})
df_frequency = df.iloc[:,range(1,27,2)]
plot_frequency = sb.heatmap(df_frequency, cmap='Blues', ax=axes[1], cbar_kws= dict(label = 'median frequency a user used'))
```

I can just show two of them in a subplot in separate diagrams.

I want to make it look like this (this is made in paint):

[image]

Also show the data side by side. Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: Like this? [How to create a heat-map with multiple colormaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036609/how-to-create-a-heat-map-with-multiple-colormaps)

Comment: @JohanC yes something similar, but I'm using Dataframe imported from CSV. They are using arrays. I wonder if seaborn or pyplot had such method

Comment: @Coder88 `df.values` or `df.to_numpy()` will give you the underlying numpy array.

Comment: @QuangHoang yes it works now. But colors of second plot are almost all look same. And how about labels and color-scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty simple solution with `mask` option:

```
mask = np.vstack([np.arange(df.shape[1])]* df.shape[0]) % 2

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

plot_precentage = sns.heatmap(df,mask=mask, cmap='Reds', ax=axes, 
                              cbar_kws={'format': '%.0f%%',
                                        'label': '% used in past 12 months'}
                             )

plot_frequency = sns.heatmap(df, mask=1-mask, cmap='Blues', ax=axes,
                             cbar_kws= dict(label = 'median frequency a user used')
                            )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, I don't understand why the red scale is showing from 0 to 350% in your output. In my output it correctly shows 0 - ca 80%. But my problem is solved, thank you for your time.