# Combine 2 heatmaps in one chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

In my problem at hand, I want to combine 2 heatmaps in one chart. The following example creates a heatmap that captures the number of units sold with stores on the x-axis and books on the y-axis. Now, it is reasonable to assume that the units are sold through two different distribution channels: stores (S) and online (O).

Instead of displaying the different channels in two different heatmaps, I want to display the two channels side-by-side (spliting mechanism shown by the blue line for Store A). This also implies that the color for the same store can be different depending on the distribution channel, as shown for Books 2 and 4 for Store A, respectively. Ideally, I would also have two colormaps, but if that's not easily achievable, the similar colormap might suffice.

Example map:

[image]

Code to reproduce this map:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randint(2, 100, size=(7, 6))
x = ["Store {}".format(i) for i in list("ABCDEF")]
y = ["Book {}".format(i) for i in range(1, 8)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap="Wistia")

# set xlabels
ax.set_xticks(list(range(0, 6, 1)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x, rotation=45)
# set ylabels
ax.set_yticks(list(range(0, 7, 1)))
ax.set_yticklabels(y)
# white grid
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, 6, 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-0.5, 7, 1), minor=True)
ax.grid(which='minor', axis='both', linestyle='-', color='white', linewidth=2)
#resize
ax.set_aspect('auto')
# add colorbar
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I wish to confirm if you expect the splitting line (as shown for Store A) to exist across all stores.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Exactly, the split of the two distribution channels (S/O) should be shown for all stores. I just showed it Exemplars for store A. This also means that for the other stores depending on the channel there can be differences in the color for the same book.

Comment: See also [How to create a heat-map with multiple colormaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036609/how-to-create-a-heat-map-with-multiple-colormaps) and [plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output (with similar colorbars) can be very much achieved by *creating a data frame in which alternate columns are data from channel S and A*.

Then the code you have written is already in a right condition to get the expected output with minor changes:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# Arrange alternate columns with data from channel S and A
data = np.random.randint(2, 100, size=(7, 12))

x = ["Store {}".format(i) for i in list("AABBCCDDEEFF")] 
y = ["Book {}".format(i) for i in range(1, 8)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap="Wistia")

# set xlabels
ax.set_xticks(list(np.arange(0.5, 12.5, 2)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x[::2], rotation=45)

# set ylabels
ax.set_yticks(list(range(0, 7, 1)))
ax.set_yticklabels(y)

# white grid
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, 12, 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-0.5, 7, 1), minor=True)
ax.grid(which='minor', axis='both', 
linestyle='-', color='white', linewidth=2)

for i in range(0, 12, 2):
    ax.text(-0.25 + i , -0.65, "S")
    ax.axvline(i + 0.5, lw=1, color='black', linewidth=0.7)
    ax.text(0.75 + i , -0.65, "O")

ax.set_aspect('auto')

plt.colorbar(im).ax.set_title("O")
plt.colorbar(im).ax.set_title("S")
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Figure:

[image]